# Error assignment of read-only location '__result.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<long long int>()'

Tags: c++

Some error while doing xor to all elements of a `std::set`.
below is partial code. Don't know much about `std::transform`. help pls :)

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    #define ll long long int 

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
       set<ll> e1 ;//suppose i had inserted few elements in it!
       ll x2;
       cin>>x2;
       //now i want to xor all elements of set with x2.
       std::transform(std::begin(e1), std::end(e1), std::begin(e1), [=](ll x){return x2^x;});
       return 0;
     }
```

Error message:

> Error assignment of read-only location
>   '__result.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator*()'

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), retake [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and reread about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `#define ll long long int` - Don't do this! If you really want an alias for a type, use `typedef long long int ll;` or `using ll = long long int;`; don't use a preprocessor macro for such things.

Comment: By the way, also don't forget how to create a [mcve] to show us, one that replicates the problem as well as is copyable so we can test it ourselves. Your code won't build, even if we put it in a function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "Your code won't build" - You know that's kind of the point of the question, don't you?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Well it won't build because of other and unrelated errors. Any unrelated error in the shown code will only distract from the real problem.

Comment: After your edit the code still have unrelated errors, and you should also take some time to read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: @SebastianRedl  i changed "#define ll long long int " to  typedef long long int ll;  But still the  same error , i guess this is not our concern of discussion.

Answer (score 7):

You can't. A `std::set` doesn't allow in-place modification of its elements, so its iterators can never be written to. Thus, you can't use a `std::set` as the target of a `std::transform`.

You'd have to create a new set from the elements of the old, transforming as you go. (For example, by using a [`std::inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) as the target of the `std::transform`.)

Are you sure you can't just use `std::vector`?

Comment: No i cant. Sir if i do this std::transform(std::begin(e1),std::end(e1),std::begin(e2),[=](ll x){return x2^x;}); where e2 is other empty set. Still it shows the same error.

Comment: @BharathChoudhary Which is why you need `std::inserter(e2)`, not `std::begin(e2)`.

Comment: I did  use std::inserter(e2), its shows error   no matching function for call to 'inserter(std::set<long long int>&)'